# Responsive list of divs in bootstraps

Tags: html, css

I have created this table with divs. This is how it is displayed on the screen:

[image]

```
 <div class="row my-2">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong>Source</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong>Target Language</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong> Price per word</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong>Total words</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong>Total per language</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
     <strong>Total Price</strong>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And this for entries in tables:

```html
<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-lg-2 mx-auto my-auto">
    script.txt (English)
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 mx-auto">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      German
    </div>
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      Chineese
    </div>
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      French
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      $0.04
    </div>
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      $0.05
    </div>
    <div class="row mx-auto">
      $0.04
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 mx-auto my-auto">
    × 1245
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this on large screen, but not on mobile view.

What can be done to get this same table on mobile view.

Comment: Hi Hritika, why didn't you use the table tag?

Comment: If you're trying to use Bootstrap tables in a mobile view, I suggest you review the documentation on Bootstrap tables in mobile, which you can see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

Comment: If you have a lot of columns, you can try horizontal scrolling